# User Information of following users

Tags: laravel, vue.js, lumen

I am working with lumen and Vuejs and I have a problem with my following system. I can follow and unfollow other users, and I also can show the posts of the users.

```
      $test = Posts::join('followers', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'followers.follower_id')
                  ->join('users', 'followers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                  ->where('users.id', $user->id)
                  ->get();
```

My result is this, for all Users I'm following:

```
{
    "id": 221,
    "user_id": 221,
    "content": "Mein erster Post hier :) Hi!!! ",
    "created_at": "2019-07-01 09:04:44",
    "updated_at": "2019-07-17 18:52:33",
    "follower_id": 217,
    "follows": 1,
    "username": "cicek",
    "email": "cicek@cicek.de",
    "avatar": "photo.png"
}
```

My Problem is, the username is the name of the user who is logged in. I want to get the Data of the followed user, with the follower_id, so I can display it in the feed of the logged in user. So know I can just display the content of the posts, but I cannot display the owner of the post in the feed.

I also think it is not necessary to see the username and other data's of the logged in user, but I was not able to do it in another way. I also tried to make some relationships in the Posts Model

```
      public function ownerPosts()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
        }
```

But it didn't worked, because so I could see every person who is following the user.

On the profiles I display the posts like this:

```
      $post_query = Posts::with('comments')
             ->with('comments.owner')
             ->with('likes.isLiked')
             ->withCount('likes')
             ->where('user_id', $user->id)
             ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
             ->limit($request->limit)
             ->get();
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Followers are also user, so in this case you can join the user twice by giving different name. I made a query, you can try or make it fix for your use. I guess you got the concept, if I'm missing something just let me know.

```
$test = Posts::select('posts.*','users.*', followers.*, follower.name as follower_name
                  ->join('followers', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'followers.follower_id')
                  ->join('users as users', 'followers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                  ->join('users as follower', 'followers.follower_id', '=', 'users.id')
                  ->where('users.id', $user->id)
                  ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I try this, the third join with the users.id takes the id of the logged in user and not the id of the follower_id. So it gives me an error.

Comment: @Rosina try changing the name or users and followers, give them u1,u2 and also in other position change these. Also if you can share the post table structure.

Comment: So I tried it again, and know I'm not getting any errors, but I don't get any data back. The result is like this: [ ].
My post table structure looks like this: id, user_id, content, created_at and updated_at

Comment: @Rosina it should work, check if the datas are properly there. If datas are missing it will return empty [].

Comment: i leftjoined the last join, know I'm getting data, but the follower_name is null.

Comment: Show me the query

Comment: ´´´       $test = Posts::select('posts.*','users.*', 'followers.*', 'follower.username as follower_name')
                  ->join('followers', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'followers.follower_id')
                  ->join('users as users', 'followers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                  ->leftjoin('users as follower', 'followers.follower_id', '=', 'users.id')
                  ->where('users.id', $user->id)
                  ->get(); ´´´ Thats the query

Comment: follower.username or it should be follower.name , check your users table

Comment: Its username in my users table, not just name

Comment: I also tried it to make it work with relationships, and it worked but the problem was, that I got the data of every user I was following to every post. The query is above: public function ownerposts().

Comment: `$data=ChannelMessageFavourite::select('channel_message_favourites.*','member_messages.*', 'u.*', 'f.name as follower_name')
            ->join('member_messages', 'member_messages.id', '=', 'channel_message_favourites.channel_message_id')
            ->join('users as u', 'member_messages.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
            ->join('users as f', 'member_messages.admin_id', '=', 'f.id')
            ->get(); `
this is totally working which is almost same as yours. now without knowing the database I'm hopeless

Comment: Yeah its almost the same, and I double checked everything but cannot find whats wrong. My users table looks like this: id, username, email, password, avatar, token, created and updatet_at. Posts table: id, user_id, content, created and updatet_at. And at least my followers table: id, user_id, follower_id, follows, created and updatet_at